# Reuse datastore models across services without symlink

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

If App Engine service A and service B both depend on a datastore model, is there an effective way to share that model between both services without either duplicating the model or symlinking the file the model class definition is declared in?

Would like to hear anyone's experience with this. Maybe storing the shared dependencies in Cloud Storage and pulling the relevant files from there?

Comment: I've never tried this, but you could "vendor" the shared packages by placing them in your `/lib` folder? However, if both services depend on shared models it sounds more like an architectural issue, as the services are not independent.  Perhaps consider having the model in one service, and have that service provide an API for the other service to access the model data?

Comment: @snakecharmerb the vendoring idea is interesting, but it's still a duplication of the data model for each service, unless there is an application-wide lib directory that's accessible that I'm not aware of? It's definitely to some degree architectural, as the services both depend on a datastore entity key object. Normally I would expose the key via an API from one service to another, but in this particular use case, it's more ideal to expose the model itself (and its class methods).

Comment: [Vendoring](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library) is specific to the standard environment, but as far as I know the contents of the `/lib` folder are globally accessible within the application.  For flexible environment you could make your models file into a pip-installable package to achieve a simialr effect.  I've never tried either of these options, though I expect to be facing simialr issues - how handle common code in a micro-services application - in the near future.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'll look into trying this, but my first reaction is it seems like that's a violation of separation of concerns if packages vendored in one service is global to all services for the application.

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer, just some considerations.

I see a few difficulties to consider if using GCS for storing the shared models:

- importing the models in your app code would be a bit more complex, you'll need to use GCS libraries to read the file(s) for dynamic importing as they would not be available in the local filesystem. As a side effect of the dynamic importing you may loose some development capabilities in your IDE (like auto-completion, object structure verifications, etc) Preserving them *might* be possible, but probably not trivial.
- splitting the model definitions across model files (for partial reuse, inheritance and/or inter-model references for example) would not be a simple task. The point above would need to be addressed in the model files as well, in addition to the application code.
- deploying the app code on GAE and the models on GCP will always be non-atomic, extra care for coordinating the deployments and probably backward/forward compatibility would be needed to minimize/eliminate transient failures.

IMHO the symlinks would be a simpler approach.

Comment: Thanks Dan for the thoughts. I was leaning away from symlinking as that may cause headaches with changes in repository structure, but the concerns you bring up are great points.

Comment: Those changes are minimal - one-time replacement of files with symlinks, after which all changes would be concentrated in the single remaining file copy where the symlinks are pointing to. If you have branches you need to merge - also one-time conflicts per branch in the worst case. OK, maybe more, if you have multiple/nested model files.